# Save fragments state in Navigation component

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I am using new Navigation component of `Jetpack Library` and it is pretty cool but i experience an annoying problem.

I use Navigation component with Bottom navigation view and i have three fragments: Home, Profile and Settings. Home fragment has `RecyclerView` and when user clicks an item from it, a new fragment appears. The problem is when i am in some state in Home fragment and go to for example profile fragment, this state is gone and new home fragment is created and i do not want this to happen.

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue exists in current navigation. In this year's dev summit they talked about fixing that issue.

Comment: so is there another way to save state of fragments without using Navigation component until the problem is fixed?

Comment: @amr you can use view models to store the data so whenever new instance of a fragment is created, your older view model (with data from network/db already loaded in it) will connect to your newer fragment. That way you are not making heavy network/db operations when you're navigating in between different fragments in bottom nav bar. While doing so make sure you assign IDs to your views in xml especially recycler view, scroll view / nested scroll views so that they can retain their scroll position as well.